# How to split a string and find the occurence of one string in another?

Tags: php, string

I need to figure out how to do some C# code in php, and im not sure exactly how.

so first off i need the Split function, im going to have a string like

```
"identifier 82asdjka271akshjd18ajjd"
```

and i need to split the identifier word from the rest. so in C#, i used string.Split(new char{' '}); or something like that (working off the top of my head) and got two strings, the first word, and then the second part.. i understand that the php split function has been **deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0**.. so thats not an option, what are the alternatives?

and im also looking for a `IndexOf` function, so if i had the above code again as an example, i would need the location of `271` in the string, so i can generate a substring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for splitting and [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for finding the index of one string inside another.

```
$a = "identifier 82asdjka271akshjd18ajjd";
$arr = explode(' ',$a); // split on space..to get an array of size 2.
$pos = strpos($arr[1],'271'); // search for '271' in the 2nd ele of array.
echo $pos; // prints 8
```